# Calibre server through computer name

Tags: server, calibre

I use Calibre to manage my ebooks.

Caibre has a server option, which I can access on my Ubuntu 12.10 machine through the link: 
`http://my_computer_name:8080` or through `http://my_IP_address:8080`.

On another machine on the local network, I can access the server through the IP address but not through the computer name. Since the IP address changes every time I connect, I wish to be able to connect through the computer name.

How do I go about it?

Some information:

There's a router which manages my network but I do not have much information on it, since I'm not administrator of the network. However, both machines are on the same local network.

`cat /etc/hostname` gives `username-computer-name`

`avahi-resolve --name username-computer-name.local` gives something like this: `username-computer-name.local ff70::465d:57ef:fed5:dd46`. (What is this?)

`avahi-resolve -n username-computer-name.local` gives my my 192.168.0.xxx IP address, the one assigned by the router.

`ping username-computer-name` gives: `64 bytes from username-computer-name (127.0.1.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.017 ms` but my IP address accessible through the network is not 127.0.1.1 but 192.168.0.xxx. I can successfully ping the latter address as well.

Comment: 1) the `avahi-resolve` syntax you're using is wrong (missing `--name`). 2) `avahi-resolve` will use IPv6 link-local whereas Ubuntu is configured to use regular IPv4 addresses (as shown in my answer) 3) Don't use `avahi-resolve` as it's not the same as resolving in other applications. Use `ping` for example instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has link-local multicast DNS enabled by default using Avahi. This is a short version of [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57577/23363) on pretty much the same question on UL. This is a way completely independent on how your local network was set up, so this should work in most cases, even if you're not using a local DNS server on the machines.

*I'm assuming both hosts here are in the same LAN (layer 2 network segment). In most set ups there's just one of it in a home network and both wireless and wired are connected at layer 2.*

Suppose one host is called `host1` and the other `host2`, then you should be able to talk to each other using `host1.local` and `host2.local`. That's it.

But, how does this relate to regular name resolving? `.local` is "special" and your Ubuntu system is configured to try `mDNS` as well:

```
cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
```

Check your hostname configuration in `/etc/hostname` for this. It should be a single word and you've assigned it during the installation of Ubuntu.

Comment: This does not work on my system. Any clues how to diagnose?